# not able to execute multiple commands on multiple linux machines?

Tags: linux, ssh, command, scp, remote

I have around 50 ubuntu machines on which I need to run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/pip /tmp/
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --no-index --find-links="file:///tmp/pip/" kazoo
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/parallel-gnu.tar /tmp/
sudo su
cd /tmp
tar -xvf parallel-gnu.tar
cd parallel-20101112/
sudo ./configure && make && make install
sudo mkdir /appholder
sudo chown -R golden /appholder/
sudo mkdir -p /opt/lnp
sudo scp todd@machineA.host.com:/keeper/data/release/comp.tar.gz /opt/lnp/
sudo chown -R golden /opt/lnp/
sudo mkdir -p /comp/core
sudo chown -R golden /comp/core
```

So I made a shell script file with above commands as `commands.sh` and I created another file called `machines.text` in which I have all 50 machines.

My list of machines is in this file `machines.text`:

```
somemachineA
somemachineB
```

And my commands are in this file `commands.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install htop
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/pip /tmp/
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --no-index --find-links="file:///tmp/pip/" kazoo
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/parallel-gnu.tar /tmp/
sudo su
cd /tmp
tar -xvf parallel-gnu.tar
cd parallel-20101112/
sudo ./configure && make && make install
sudo mkdir /appholder
sudo chown -R golden /appholder/
sudo mkdir -p /opt/lnp
sudo scp todd@machineA.host.com:/keeper/data/release/comp.tar.gz /opt/lnp/
sudo chown -R golden /opt/lnp/
sudo mkdir -p /comp/core
sudo chown -R golden /comp/core
```

I have a script like this `execute.sh` which I am running like this `./execute.sh machines.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "###################################################"
    echo "Machine Name: $line"
    scp commands.sh $line:/tmp/commands.sh
    ssh -t $line 'script /dev/null . /tmp/commands.sh'
    echo "###################################################"
done < "$1"
```

After running above, I see below error and it hasn't executed any of those commands in `somemachineA`:

```
todd@testMachine:~$ ./execute.sh machines.text
###################################################
Machine Name: somemachineA
todd@somemachineA's password:
commands.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                100%  104     0.1KB/s   00:00
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
todd@somemachineA's password:
Script started, file is /dev/null
Script done, file is /dev/null
todd@somemachineA:/home/todd$ somemachineB: command not found
```

What wrong I am doing and how can I execute multiple linux commands on multiple linux machines?

Comment: read into [pssh](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)

Comment: Why `script /dev/null ...`?

Comment: use `ssh -tt`, which will force pseudo-terminal allocation even from script.

Comment: a little overkill, but I really like mcollective. https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective

Comment: try using [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) it should work like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
ssh -t $line 'script /dev/null . /tmp/commands.sh'
```

by

```
ssh  $line 'bash /tmp/commands.sh'
```

- you are scripting to /dev/null ??
- if you are executing command interactively, tty will be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available for doing what you want. My favourite is [pdsh](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html), which includes a `pdcp` (multi-host scp), `pdsh` (multi-host ssh), and `dshbak` (display multi-host output grouped by host) - `dshbak` is useful because pdsh executes commands in parallel on multiple hosts, not one host after the other.  I've used pdsh many times on clusters, VMs, cloud servers, and small and large groups of physical machines.  It does the job well and is easy to set up.

pdsh is available pre-packaged packaged for most distros.

To use it, you'd create a hosts file (by default, /etc/genders) containing hostnames and a comma-separated list of "group" names that they belong to.  Each host can belong to one or more groups - e.g. some hosts might be in group "webserver", some in group "dbserver", and all hosts in group "all".  For example:

```
somemachineA all
somemachineB all
```

Then you would use pdcp to copy your script to all hosts in group "all":

```
pdcp -g all commands.sh /tmp/
```

(Note: /tmp on the remote hosts must be mounted with exec privs - default for most filesystems but it is not unusual for /tmp to be mounted noexec for security purposes.  in that case, either pdcp the script to somewhere else or invoke it with, e.g. `bash /tmp/commands.sh` rather than just `/tmp/commands.sh`?)

Then execute the script on all hosts:

```
pdsh -g all /tmp/commands.sh >& /tmp/commands.log
```

(Note: this assumes that ssh has been configured on all hosts for password-less login, i.e. using an ssh key rather than a password.  if this is not the case, it's probably best not to redirect output to a log file, because that would make interactive use difficult.  You really should configure the remote hosts for ssh key access, and then disable password logins)

when it's finished you can view the log with dshbak:

```
dshbak /tmp/commands.log | less
```

Finally, one useful thing to know about pdsh etc is that, by default, it will try to use rsh rather than ssh.  I have no idea why because no-one sane uses rsh any more...it's easily fixed, though, just create a file called `/etc/pdsh/rcmd_default` and add one line containing just `ssh`.