# Copy an executable to an arbitrary number of hosts?

Tags: executable, deployment

How can I copy an executable file to an arbitrary number of hosts and have it run on all of them? Sending this .exe to 20 hosts.

Trying to have the files go into the /tmp directory.  Setting up a lab and trying to practice deployments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered configuration management for this? E.g. ansible or whatnot

Comment: `for host in $(cat /path/to/hostlist); do scp /path/to/myfile.exe $host:/tmp/; done`

Comment: there are numerous similar questions and answers on this site, and numerous tools for the job (including pdsh, clusterssh, mussh, kanif, and more) .  My preferred tool is pdsh - e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226959/7696

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I use to distribute my shell configuration files; it's easily adapted.

```
#!/bin/sh
# copy selected files to other machines

FILES=".cshrc .login .profile"
HOSTS="kipling khan nag smith wolf"

h=${HOSTS}
if [ $1x != x ] ; then
   h=$1
fi

for i in $h ; do
    echo ${i}:
    for f in ${FILES}; do
        (cd ~; scp ${f} ${i}:.)
    done  
done
```

You can obviously change the precise source and destination as required. Note that if it is given an argument, the file(s) are sent to that one specified host. Use:

```
FILES=$(cat file-containing-list-of-files)
```

if you want to have that list in a file, and decouple it from the script. The same could apply to the list of hosts.

These days, I would probably use `rsync` rather than `scp` as it will preserve the file mode, etc.